# C - Return pointer of first element in linked list (string)

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, c-strings, singly-linked-list

My function needs to return the pointer of the first element in the linked list *String s* after adding a character.

```
typedef struct String
{
    char cChar; //data of type char stored in a node
    struct String* strNext; //pointer to the next node of the linked list
}String;

String create ()
{
    String* strTemp = NULL;

    //dynamic memory allocation
    strTemp = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String));
    //to make sure returned character is null after creation
    strTemp->cChar = '\0';
    strTemp->strNext = NULL;

    return *strTemp;
}

void concat(String *a, String *b){
    if (a->strNext == NULL)
        a->strNext = b;
    else
        concat(a->strNext,b);
}

/**
 * @brief Adds a character c to the end of the String s
 * 
 * @param String s : string to be manipulated
          char c : character to be added
          
 * @return String : the pointer of the first element in String s
 */
String add (String s, char c){
    String* strTemp = NULL;
    strTemp = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String));
    strTemp->cChar = c;
    strTemp->strNext = '\0';
    concat(&s, strTemp);
    
    return s; <--- this is where it should return
}
```

The string needs to be a linked list and the add function is called like this:
`add(s1, 'H');`

I can't get a hold of linked lists in C.

Comment: To begin with, the function should be `String *add(String *s, char c)` ...  You also need to `malloc`, as right now you assign `strTemp` a NULL value and then start dereferencing it to write at that memory location.

Comment: You have the same issue with the `create` function.  It should be `String *create()` and it should return `strTemp`.  In your `add` function, it would then make sense to do `String* strTemp = create();`

Comment: @paddy our professor gave us a bunch of functions to work on (https://ibb.co/xsc1zBs) and I have no idea if I can change how it looks. Do you think it can work without it?

Comment: I'm not going to follow that link, but the short answer is no: your functions must deal with pointers.  You have almost certainly misunderstood some part of the assignment and you should consult your professor for clarification.

Comment: Why did you post a screenshot of the task instead of copying it as text into the question. No one likes following external links and no one like pictures where text would be better. You cannot copy function prototypes from that picture.

Comment: Did anyone request you to use a linked list for this assignment? In C a "string" is defined as a nul-terminated character sequence. Defining a linked list and call it `String` is highly confusing and misleading.

Comment: @Gerhardh yea it must be a linked list as i stated

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the screenshot you linked does not contain that requirement.

Comment: @Gerhardh it was mentioned after she posted the required int main() code.

Comment: If you got more requirements, why not posting them? Then we can see if there are other issues with your approach. Also what is the type `Set` that is used as return type for `add` in your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the function `create` produces a memory leak because within the function a memory is allocated and not freed and the function returns a copy of the created object.

You should declare and define the function at least like

```
String * create( void )
{
    String* strTemp = NULL;

    //dynamic memory allocation
    strTemp = (String*)malloc(sizeof(String));
    //to make sure returned character is null after creation
    if ( strTemp != NULL )
    {
        strTemp->cChar = '\0';
        strTemp->strNext = NULL;
    }

    return strTemp;
}
```

The function `concat` is confusing. It should create a new list based on the passed two lists.

The function add invokes undefined behavior because it uses a null pointer

```
String* strTemp = NULL;
```

to access a memory

```
strTemp->cChar = c;
```

The function should look the following way

```
int add (String *s, char c )
{
    while ( s->next != NULL ) s = s->next;

    s->next = malloc( sizeof( String ) );
    int success = s->next != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        s->cChar = c;
        s->next->cChar = '\0';
        s->next->next = NULL;
    }

    return success;
}
```

It is supposed that the list can not be a null pointer.

If you want that the function create would return an object of the type String then the function will look like

```
String create( void )
{
    String strTemp = { .cChar = '\0', .next = NULL };

    return strTemp;
}
```